# Geolite2 files taking up space on disk

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, geolite2

Checking the disk use of my hosting account I have discovered a section called "Another use" with more than 500MB (my plan has 2GB). I have contacted to them about that and they said me this:

"It looks like you have any plugin using geolite, which has generated files like these in the Tmp directory:

GeoLite2-Country.mmdb-ueb25F.tmp
GeoLite2-Country.mmdb-UgJn8x.tmp"

I'm not sure about what these files are, or which plugins are creating them. My candidates are Amazon Associates Link Builder (Amazon's oficial plugin), Amazon Auto Links, Google Analytics for WordPress (MonsterInsights)...

Any idea would be appreciated!